# conditionally load some html based on window size

Tags: jquery

I want to load a map, but I only want to load it if I can assume that they are on wifi. Since there is no real way to do this, I'm going to just assume that if the window width is larger then 600, that they are. Loading the iframe is a little more tricky - but just loading an image would get me started. This works, but It doesn't seem to work if I shove a bunch of complicated html in there. I'm not really sure that I should have scripts in the middle of my html anyways.

```
<script>
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 600) {
    document.write("<h1>Hello</h1>");
  }
</script>
```

I thought this [THIS ARTICLE](http://24ways.org/2011/conditional-loading-for-responsive-designs/) would help me, but it is a little over my head.

Does anyone have some tips or some reading for me?

Thanks.

## EDIT: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/m3jZz/)

maybe I should have an eternal .html file and pull that in... ?

There are problems with escaping and stuff - when there are tons of crazy characters in embed codes etc...

Comment: You might want to consider deciding how much content to display based on what fits in the window size, not on some assumption about the bandwith.  You can do this with CSS media queries.  Your target audience can help you make assumptions about bandwith more than the size of the window.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I am very familiar with responsive design. I cannot however, use an @media rule to decide whether or not to load a google map. For small devices, I have a link to the map, and on larger devices (that probably have higher bandwidth) I want to load the google map iframe etc. It's just for example. Browsers download whatever is display: none; and I can't have 2 of everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never use `document.write()` it not a good practice to use it. Instead you can use `.innerHTML` of javascript or `.html()` of jQuery. jQuery has several other methods doing this kind of work like `.append()`, `.appendTo()` similarly `.prepend()`, `.prependTo()`:

#### jQuery:

```
$(function () {
   var width = $(window).width();
   if (width <= 600) {
      $('<p>lesser than 600</p>').appendTo('body');
   } else {
      $('<p>greater than 600</p>').appendTo('body');
   }
});
```

#### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gWfe4/)

#### CSS MEDIA QUERIES:

Also this kind of thing you can achieve with css media queries too:

```
span {
   color:green;
   font-weight:bold;
}
.div600 {
   display:none
}
.divOther {
   display:block
}
@media all and (max-width:600px) { /****<-----This media query******/
   .div600 {
       display:block
   }
   .divOther {
       display:none
   }
}
```

#### [DEMO FIDDLE CSS MEDIA QUERY](http://jsfiddle.net/mXQ9H/)

Comment: Media queries are great. I couldn't live without them, but I can't have 2 versions of everything - and they load the images etc, anyways - even when display: none;

Comment: The only thing that media queries can conditionally load as far as I know, are background images. - and I think there is still debate on that.

Comment: Media queried i use to make linear layouts for mobiles sites and i have to use it this way, I think this is way better than jquery to parse the things.

Comment: So how would you load an iframe of a google map, only if the screen was bigger then, lets say, 600px? (but not just visually...) I want to watch the site be painted in dev tools and never see this loaded etc...

Comment: I want to find a cleaner way to break out of the javascript and have the ability to grab larger chunks of html, maybe even whole .html files - but you totally answered my question @jai - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this...

```
 var width =  $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width

  if(width > 600){
      $("#articleID").html(Your_Html_Section_Which_you_want_to_put_in_article);
      //document.write("<h1>Hello</h1>");
  }
```

Comment: That is what I already have. Try putting a whole section of html in that document.write - that is what i'm trying to learn - how do load a whole sections of html into an article.  I'll update my question.