# Using JQuery to remove large HTTP requests from DOM on document(ready)

Tags: jquery, http, dom, mobile

I am using a video background for a website, and I'm hoping to reduce the load time on a mobile site by removing this element for mobile.  If I do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 
    if(windowWidth < 481) {
        $('.video').remove(); 
    } 
});
```

to measure the screen width on load, assume it is mobile, and then remove this element from the DOM, am I saving any performance with this method?

I'm guessing that is has already made an HTTP request, but if it is immediately removed, the site would "load faster" wouldn't it?

I'm hoping to avoid external libraries aside from JQuery, and I don't want to change the HTML mark up if possible.

Comment: Why not go the other way? That is, only load the video if you find that the screen is large enough.

Comment: That's a great idea.  Is there a way I can keep the HTML markup the exact same and do that with JQuery?

Comment: You probably have to remove the '.video' element from the HTML, then add it back using jquery as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15726614/1586229

Comment: Yea, that's what I was worried about.  Using `append()` wouldn't work in this case, as my HTML markup is dependent on several `if/else` statements based on Wordpress page templates.  I don't even think I could use `html()`.  This is a good idea, though, I will explore more.  Thanks!

Comment: Trying to do this on document load is too late. It is loaded by then.  Why not control this on server side (i.e. not generate video element for detected mobile devices)?